# how can i Get a list of all NFT holders in optimism

Tags: contract-development

how can i  Get a list of all NFT holders in optimismis any tools.As like trust-wallet gives the list of available NFT in the wallet.

How can we achieve that same thing?

What are the multiple ways to achieve that thing?

Comment: If you would like to code, you can use alchemy sdk
https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/alchemy-sdk-quickstart